# Angular 7, Ngrx, ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

was looking for a longer while but couldn't find anything.

I have a template like so:

```
<learning-navigation *ngIf="(_navigationSelectedSafe$ | async) == _navigationLayout.location" [(selectMode)]="_navigationModeSelected"></learning-navigation>
```

Where:

```
private _navigationSelected$: Observable<string>;
private _navigationSelectedSafe$ = new EventEmitter<any>(true);

...

this._navigationSelected$.subscribe(res => {
  ...
  this._navigationSelectedSafe$.emit(res)
});
```

with the input of learning-navigation being a setter:

```
  @Input()
  set selectMode(mode: number) {
    this.mode = mode;
  }
```

This causes the error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'selectMode: null'. Current value: 'selectMode: 1'.
```

I already tried changing the EventEmitter to a BehaviourSubject, forcing detectChanges() after ngInit and ngAfterChecked (Although this wouldn't be optimal even if it worked) and also wrapping it around in a container trying to pass the mode directly async into the component while just controlling the display with an extra if.

The current solution works and it doesn't seem there are any side effects but it throws the error regardless every time mode changes. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the rest of the logic of your component is but if it's just a presentational component you could set the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. This way the change detector will be called only when the input is updated

Comment: Changing the push detection worked. Can you please formulate it into a nice answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem indicates that there was a change of value outside Angular's change detection. This can happen for multiple reasons. In your case it's the asynchronous nature of your input I guess.

If your component is a presentational component, you can set the change detection strategy to `onPush`.

This way your change detector will run only when there's a new value on your input

example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-comp',
  templateUrl: './app-your-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-your-comp.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="_navigationSelectedSafe$ | async as selectedSafe">
  <learning-navigation *ngIf="selectedSafe == _navigationLayout.location" 
    [(selectMode)]="_navigationModeSelected"></learning-navigation>
</ng-container>
```

This will prevent the `learning-navigation` element frop being displayed when the value of your observable is null, thus erasing your error.

### EDIT

Use a timeout in your setter to resolve any further issue :

```
@Input()
set selectMode(mode: number) {
  setTimeout(() => this.mode = mode);
}
```

Comment: That's what I meant wrapping it in a container with an extra if, I already tried that. The problem is not null value, the error appears on every change, also 1->2, 2->3

Comment: That's not a solution. That's a hack

Comment: @Antonis that's indeed a workaround, but it's for an issue that does not exist in production mode.

Comment: @Antonis and this far, this is the only way I am aware of. And believe me, I have faced it many times. If you know better, please, feel free to enlighten us.

Comment: @Maryannah You can read about change detection strategies. They are useful in certain cases

Comment: @Antonis I know about CD strategies, but they're completely situational and don't directly tackle the issue of the OP, they focus on the component change detection strategy. You say my answer is a hack (which I agree), I say your solution is overkill and might not be suited to everyone facing the same issue. But glad it worked for the OP, and take my upvote !

Comment: Indeed it's for certain cases. I suggest it only when we're talking about presentational components. Thanks for the upvote